# npm Error Installing - npm ERR! cb() never called not ok code 0

Tags: node.js, npm

Windows 7 (64)
npm version 1.3.24
node version 0.10.25

When I am trying to install bower I am  getting this error message

```
C:\>npm install bower -g
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower
npm ERR! cb() never called!
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I already tried

```
npm cache clean
```

and

```
npm install - getting another error message
```

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\andpon>cd/

```
C:\>npm install
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! package.json ENOENT, open 'C:\package.json'
npm ERR! package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directo
ry.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd C:\
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.24
npm ERR! path C:\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Can any one know solution for this problem

Thanks

Comment: The first error is usually caused by the unstable network connection. About the second error, have you created a file named `package.json`  in the directory `c:/`? Usually we create `package.json` in our project directory. All the dependencies are included in this file. Then we run `npm install` in the project directory to install all the required modules.

Comment: Hi Following your answer haw can I stable network connection I am on 100mb broadband and never had problem with connection, I although have no problem to install repo when using ruby. I am not behind server proxy. All I am trying to install is bower, following instruction on zurb-Foundation. It should be strait forward but I am getting error mentioned on top of my post.

Comment: Try an npm mirror to install bower. Details: [http://blog.modulus.io/npm-mirrors](http://blog.modulus.io/npm-mirrors)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try this solution later on. And let you know how it's work

Answer (score 1):

I found an entry in a blog that resolved the issue in the following easy way by creating a symbolic link:

> For anyone wishing to still use their OS's package of node the simple solution for this is to determine where node is installed on your OS and then create a symbolic link.
>
> For example I had the issue on ubuntu and the install directory is /usr/bin. To create the symlink you can run:
>
> sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
>
> in windows you can use the mklink command.. Be sure to open the command prompt as a administrator

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error. I checked a [page](http://status.npmjs.org/#week) showing the response time of the npm registry. It was showing a bit slower response time than normally (around 1700ms 21st of March 2015) so I tried again a few hours later and then it worked.

I did not change any settings or update anything in the mean time so I guess it was some sort of timeout somewhere that caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error and I fixed it by installing Windows SDK.

If you have visual studio installed you can try to do following thing to install windows SDK:

Go to control panel -> Programs -> uninstall programs ->  right click Visual Studio NNNN installer and select"change. It will open visual studio installer and you can modify and select which components you want to install/uninstall. Make sure that you select C++ stuff, it should contain Windows SDK.

If you dont have then you need to download SDK from internet and install it.

Later I also needed to install Python 2.7 to be able to install some npm packages...

Answer (score 0):

Have a try on yarn. 
I have tried many method to solve the issue, but the error is not solved yet.
And I tried yarn, it works for me.